# Example of a quasi-open set and how the capacity of the set fits in it?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, reference-request, partial-differential-equations, metric-geometry

While going through some research papers, I came across a result of D. Bucur where the existence of a minimizer for the general $k^{th}$ eigenvalue of the Dirichlet Laplacian among a class of quasi-open sets with fixed measure was shown.

I have looked into the definition of quasi-open sets from A. Henrot, *Extremum problems for eigenvalues of elliptic operator*. But I was unable to find any insight as to what kind of sets one might expect to be quasi-open.

First, in Definition 2.4.3, they defined the capacity of a set as

> Let $D$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. For any compact subset $K$ in $D$, define
> $$\text{cap}_D(K)= \inf \left\{\int_D|\nabla v|^2: v\in C_0^{\infty}, v\geq 1 \text{ surrounding } K \right\}$$

The definition can be extended for an open subset $\omega$ of $D$ as

> $$\text{cap}_D(\omega):= \sup \{\text{cap}_D(K): K \text{ compact, } K\subset \omega\}$$

Quasi-open sets as in Definition 2.4.4 is defined as follows,

> A subset $\Omega$ of $D$ (a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$) is quasi-open if there exist a decreasing sequence of open sets $\omega_n$ such that
> $$\displaystyle \lim_{n\to +\infty} \text{cap}_D(\omega_n)=0$$
> where $\Omega \cup \omega_n$ is open for all $n$ and $\text{cap}_D(\omega_n)$ is the capacity of $\omega_n$ relative to $D$.

I would love to get an insight on how the capacity of a set fits in the definition of quasi-open sets. Also, it would be helpful if I can get a detailed example of a quasi-open set or a reference to find one.

I would also appreciate if someone can provide me with some intuition as to how to look at the idea of capacity of a set and which aspect of a set does it actually measure.

Comment: Perhaps if you post this question on MathOverflow it will get an answer. I have the same doubt as you

Comment: Also, you could check the recent book by Henrot and Pierre, *Shape Variation and Optmization*

Comment: Did you get to know the answer?